XPath using variables
Hi I have an xml as follows:
I have 3 variables tablename, fieldname and codevalue
I would like to use XPath to find the value of Description
I am trying to build the expression as below:
strExpression = "/Table={tablename}/field={fieldname}/code={codevalue}/Description]";

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <row>
    <Table>WaterLine</Table>
    <Field>AssetGroup</Field>
    <Code>0</Code>
    <Description>Unknown</Description>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Table>WaterLine</Table>
    <Field>AssetGroup</Field>
    <Code>150</Code>
    <Description>Water Main</Description>
  </row>
  <row>
    <Table>WaterLine</Table>
    <Field>AssetGroup</Field>
    <Code>155</Code>
    <Description>Service Pipe</Description>
  </row>
</root>


We even dunno what tool/language you use

An XPath expression applying a predicate that would select the Description element from a row who's child elements have certain values:
/root/row[Table='WaterLine' and Field='AssetGroup' and Code='0']/Description

Depending upon what host language or environment you are building and applying the XPath, you could either use placeholders and substitute variable values to construct the XPath or use variable references.
For instance, in XSLT you can use xsl:param to pass in the parameter value and use it in the XPath statement:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="table"/>
  <xsl:param name="field"/>
  <xsl:param name="code"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/root/row[Table=$table and Field=$field and Code=$code]/Description"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>


Thank you. I am using C#
strExpression = String.Format("/root/row[table='{0}'/field='{1}'/code='{2}']/Description",layer.Name, keyValuePair.Key.ToLower(), keyValuePair.Value);    This evaluates to  /root/row[table='WaterLine'/field='AssetGroup'/code='150']/Description

I am then using  NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);
string desc = NodeIter.Current.Value;     But this doesn't give me expected 'Water Main'

looks like you have / and aren't using and, and the element names in the XML are not lower-case so you need to fix your XPath

Ok, not sure I follow. Should this be the correct expression: /root/row[Table=WaterLine/Field=AssetGroup/Code =150]/Description

Compare that to what I posted. I do not have those slashes between Table, Field, and Code. I have and between them.

Thanks. I tried that. But val still incorrect. strExpression = "/root/row[Table='WaterLine' and Field='AssetGroup' and Code='0']/Description";
NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);
string val = NodeIter.Current.Value;

It actually works using
String val = nav.SelectSingleNode(strExpression).Value;
